# selector method of NSTImer called twice in beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler

Tags: ios, nstimer

In my beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler code block in '-applicationDidEnterBackground' method, I have nstimer implemented as follows:

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier taskId = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(print:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }];
```

And Eventhough its `repeats:NO`, 'print'method as the selector is called twice, which i can see through `NSLog`.

This timer hasn't be called from any where else than in `applicationDidEnterBackground`.

Answer (score 1):

I assure you that there is nothing wrong with:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(print:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Your 'print' method wil NOT be called twice. Your problem is with something else.
And another thing, a timer with a 0.0 time interval is rather pointless wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Hmm..yes, you are right. I don't know what was i thing. So, I jst removed the timer with the code block of 'print' method and it behaved in the same way. SO,tht behavious had nthng to do with the timer. But its seems tht the code block for 'beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler' is being executed twice. Actually, I am using CLLocation manager in my project, can that be the reason for this??

Comment: I can't be sure without seing your code. Post what you did and maybe i can help.